# Запрос в базу MySQL не добавляет данные

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
    $connect = @mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die('ERROR Conection!');
    @mysql_select_db('pepsoman',$connect) or die ('DataBase ERROR');
    $success = "";
    if(isset($_POST['reg'])){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $surname = $_POST['surname'];
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $con_password = $_POST['con_password'];
        $age = $_POST['age'];
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
        $insert = mysql_query("insert into users (name,surname,username,password,age,gender) values('$name','$surname','$username','$password','$age','$gender')");
        if($con_password != $password){
            $success = '
                <div class="panel panel-danger">
                  <div class="panel-heading">ERROR ConfirmPassword</div>
                </div>
            ';
        }
        else{
            $success = '
                <div class="panel panel-success ">
                  <div class="panel-heading">Registration</div>
                </div>
            ';
        }

    }

?>
```

Comment: вам не стоит использовать интрефейс mysql тк он является устаревшим

Comment: Если вы решили свою проблему ответами ниже то отметьте тот который вам помог

Answer (score 2):

```
    `$insert = mysql_query("insert into users (name,surname,username,password,age,gender) values('$name','$surname','$username','$password','$age','$gender')");`
```

1. Проверьте приходят ли `$_POST` данные.
2. Вообще не плохо было бы проверять перед записью в `mysql` есть ли они вообще через `isset($_POST['name'])&&isset($_POST['surname'])` и т.д.
3. В данном конкретном случае sql запрос должен выглядеть так:

   `$insert = mysql_query("insert into users (name,surname,username,password,age,gender) values('{$name}','{$surname}','{$username}','{$password}','{$age}','{$gender}')");`

или

```
 $insert = mysql_query("insert into users (name,surname,username,password,age,gender) values('".$name."','".$surname."' и т.д.
```

Так же если планируете выкладывать этот сайт в общий доступ советую почитать статьи про базовую защиту от sql-иньекций, salt и методологию хранение паролей.

Comment: тут очевидно что он закавычил переменные и превратил их в строки

Comment: да, вы правы. Моя ошибка.

Comment: кстати второй вариант более читабельный на мой взгляд, и да раз пошла пьянка, то лучше свой query билдер написать с плейсхолдерами как у функции `sprintf`
Для практики самое-то!

Answer (score 0):

На улице уже 2016, самое время освоить `mysqli` или `pdo`. И так, немного изменю твой код:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "password", "pepsoman") 
        or die(mysqli_error($link));

    if(isset($_POST['reg'])){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $surname = $_POST['surname'];
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $con_password = $_POST['con_password'];
        $age = $_POST['age'];
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
        $result = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO users (name, surname, username, password, age, gender) 
        VALUES ('$name','$surname','$username','$password','$age','$gender')");

        if(mysqli_affected_rows($result)>0){
           echo 'Добавлено';
        }

    }
```

- Данные которые ты получаешь POST методом надо чистить. `strip_tags`, `mysqli_real_escape_string` и тд, это как минимум.

Знак @ перед ф-цией отключает вывод ошибки, это не хорошо

Comment: Процедурный стиль...ммм проще тогда использовать просто mysql и не париться =)

Comment: я добавил @ потому что у меня выводится ошибка есть новая база установить новую базу или что-то вроде того я работаю с помощью WAMPSERVER 3.0.6

Comment: @HarutKostanyan а какая ошибка вам выводится?

Comment: @HarutKostanyan незнаю что у вас за логика, но если есть ошибка, её надо исправить, а не скрыть. Без разницы какой у вас сервер, а ошибка выводилась наверное из за неправильного соединения с базой. В любом случае потратьте 30-40 минуть, чтобы разобраться с `mysqli` как минимум. Плюс, еще надо очищать данные при получении. При желание, гугл вас очень обрадует.